# My CalDav client c# return 400 bad request, how to fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, caldav

I have create a sample CalDav client for read and write event in a Zimbra calendar, but when i try to make connect the request return "400 bad request".
I use DDay.iCal library.

```
public static Stream ExectueMethod (string username, string password, string caldevURI, string methodName, WebHeaderCollection headers, string content, string contentType)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpGetRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(caldevURI);
    httpGetRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    httpGetRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
    httpGetRequest.Method = methodName;

    if (headers != null && headers.HasKeys())
    {
        httpGetRequest.Headers = headers;
    }

    byte[] optionsArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);

    httpGetRequest.ContentLength = optionsArray.Length;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentType))
    {
         httpGetRequest.ContentType = contentType;
    }

    Stream requestStream = httpGetRequest.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(optionsArray, 0, optionsArray.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse httpGetResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpGetRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = httpGetResponse.GetResponseStream();

    return ResponseStream;
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to help you debug such an issue by just showing us a piece of code without giving any context. Please provide some context about the particular operation that is failing, and provide the network exchange: HTTP request (with headers and body) and HTTP response  (with headers and body)